# How To Group By Only Some Rows

Tags: plsql, group-by

I have some records.

```
 ID      Salary    WillGroupBy   Amount
 ----------------------------------------
 6320     100        1            15
 6320     150        1            20
 6694     200        0            25
 6694     300        0            30
 7620     400        1            45
 7620     500        1            50
```

How can I group by only which "WillGroupBy = 1" records?

(I will SUM Salary and Amount columns)
I want to get this result:

```
 ID      Salary    WillGroupBy   Amount
 ----------------------------------------
 6320     250        1            35
 6694     200        0            25
 6694     300        0            30
 7620     900        1            95
```

Can you help me please :( ?

---

**Solution:**

```
SELECT ID, SUM(Salary) Salary, WillGroupBy, SUM(Amount) Amount
FROM YourTable
where WILLGROUPBY = 0
union all
SELECT ID, SUM(Salary) Salary, WillGroupBy, SUM(Amount) Amount
FROM YourTable
where WILLGROUPBY = 1
group by ID, WillGroupBy
```

I used this solution via [Erhan](http://www.erhancetin.com.tr/).

I would to know that how it could be in another way.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database, e.g. mysql, sql-server, oracle, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With MySQL you can do:

```
SELECT ID, SUM(Salary) Salary, WillGroupBy, SUM(Amount) Amount, @row := @row + 1
FROM YourTable
JOIN (SELECT @row := 0) v
GROUP BY ID, IF(WillGroupBy = 1, -1, @row)
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f91a8/2)

Comment: Thanks a lot Barmar !
But I will use in Pl/sql.
I will not use in a package so I need a solution without any parameter.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know PL/SQL, so I don't know how to translate this.

Comment: Some databases have a `rowid()` function, you can use that instead of the `@row` variable. And you may have to use a `CASE` expression instead of `IF()` function.